# Server not start in low battery (Network UPS Tools)

Tags: ups, battery, nut

I have server (Centos 6.5 + nut-2.6.5 + Powercom BNT-600AP USB) 
everything works well, UPS picks up problems with electricity. When no electricity more than 10 minutes UPS shutdown the server, and turns the server when power is restored.

When no electricity for a long time battery discharged completely.

**My problem:**
When the server is loaded with a discharged battery. while loading services NUT is checking batteries. Because not had time to to recharge the battery ups fails this test and lose power to the server. Server loaded again start from the beginning and at the time of check battery again lost electricity because the battery is low. And so along the rim is about 10 minutes until the battery is charged and will pass the test and then the server is working fine.

Advise the best solution to this problem? Maybe can turn off this test on boot? Or service may start after 10 minutes? Please share experiences who will encountered such a problem.